# Why is Swift/Core Location showing my lat/long location as being in San Francisco -- even tho I'm in New York?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Hey everyone — I have written some code that identifies location via CLLocation, then converts that lat/long value to a city with CLGeoCoder().

It's working in that the code runs and id's a location -- except I am in New York, and it keeps identifying me as being in San Francisco!

Can you spot any clear mistakes I'm making in the code below? Thank you!

```
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
        if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.delegate = nil
            let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
            geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler:
                {
                    placemarks, error -> Void in

                    guard let placeMark = placemarks?.first else { return }

                    if let locationName = placeMark.location {
                        print(locationName)
                    }

                    if let street = placeMark.thoroughfare {
                        print(street)
                    }

                    if let city = placeMark.subAdministrativeArea {
                        print(city)
                    }

                    if let zip = placeMark.isoCountryCode {
                        print(zip)
                    }

                    if let country = placeMark.country {
                        print(country)
                    }
            })

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Because that's the default for the simulator. Look at Simulator|Debug|Location.

Comment: You can enter coordinates into the simulator under Debug/Location if you want to simulate your own location.

Comment: thank you, everyone, you are correct — by looking at debug/location i was able to hardcode lat/long, and now the code is working. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Run your app on a *device* (such as an actual iPhone) if you want to use location services to detect your actual location. Testing such code on a Simulator is pretty much pointless.

Comment: thank you, this is correct -- it was the simulator using prescribed lat/long that was giving me wrong location, thanks!

Comment: @Keith Please indicate that your question has been resolved by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that best resolved your issue.